# Launch a process with the "Run As..." dialog

Tags: c#, authentication, identity, runas

I've got an application that uses the current user credentials to connect to a server and run some performance tests.

For numerous reasons, impersonation isn't a viable option. Instead, I'd like to give the user a "Switch User" button which re-launches the process but shows the `Run As...` dialog.

I can't see an option on `Process.Start()` or the Associated `ProcessStartInfo`. There is an option to provide a username/password I've captured but I'd rather not be involved in the process at all and just let windows handle it. Just using the `runas` verb merely prompts to elevate but if the current user is a local admins,  there's no option to provide a different username.

Is there a way to do this? I know there's a command-line `runas.exe` but that's not a great user experience

Comment: Have you tried the `RunAsUser` verb instead?

Comment: @Jester I found that verb after asking this question. Unfortunately, when that's used, `Process.Start` returns `null` instead of a process id (it returns while the dialog is visible, before the process launches). It appears as if the dialog is hosted by the current process until it's successfully completed. That means there's no way to check for the new process launching and if I close the old one too soon, it removes the dialog. At the moment, I'm using `RunAsUser` and just relying on the user to close the old process but it's a real kludge. I should've added that to my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at the process.start() documentation? Never tried this, but looks like they have you covered:

```
public static Process Start(
    string fileName,
    string userName,
    SecureString password,
    string domain
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, that means I need to capture the username and password myself with all the associated security issues (eg making sure the password string isn't recoverable from memory). I'd rather avoid the issue entirely and let the OS handle it if possible.  That said,  thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Sure, you would have the user enter their credentials.  Not sure how you would avoid the memory bit as most security products work like this, but a suggestion you probably can't use would be to encrypt it as soon as it's entered, send the creds to your server, and decrypt it on your server + you're not sending cleartext pwd over the net then.  The bigger picture here is if your memory isn't secure you probably have much bigger issues than credentials used to query "performance tests".  Then again for all I know you work for the DoD and have to adhere to that security stack.

Comment: I'm not doing this across a network (the auth). I want to emulate a user (shift) right-clicking an executable and choosing "Run As". There's already a `SecureString` class to handle passwords but it's a pain to work with (See the [MDSN Page, especially the remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Nothing so lofty as DoD but we do touch classified info now and then, so having plain text passwords in memory is a monumental undertaking in terms of auditing/risk analysis/sign-off to replicate functionality that already exists in the OS